# How to Compile arrays from many txt file into one array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have observations txt file, number of files equals day in year. 
Column 1 and 2 in txt files are time and obsearved results, some of them miss.

I want to combile 2nd column of each file within one big array.

I tried to create X Cell as big array. its size as (desired column, desired row)
and tried fill cell with a = X(:,1) but it's not solve.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the problem is that each file has a different number of elements.

Assuming the data from each file are in a cell array `A`, then you can form a new array as follows:

```
n = numel(A);
m = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1), A);
B = NaN(max(m), n);
for i = 1:n
    B(1:m(i),i) = A{i}(:,2);
end
```

However, this doesn't align the times of the observations between the files. Comment if you need to do that too.